# How to convert a jpeg image to an svg in octave?

Tags: image-processing, svg, png, octave

I have a black n white image which i would first like to convert into a png with a transparent background such that only the black part of the image remains. Using this output image i want to convert it to svg. All of this through code which can be connected to a back-end of a server. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean a bi-level image with just pure black and pure white, or a greyscale image with intermediate shades of grey as well? Can you execute a command-line program that does the job in your Octave environment?

Comment: The image to start with will be a bi-level image. As far as command line execution is concerned, any solution will do but should be able to deploy this code on a java / php back end. An android app should be able to download the svg from the server.

Comment: I am new to image processing so I have no clue about the "how and what" of octave. The svg is required so that I can implement vectordrawables in android.

Comment: jpeg is a raster graphic format, svg a vector graphic format. In principle, they cannot be easily converted into each other. SVG can, however, be used as a container that can embed raster graphics. Why do you need an SVG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain this will always work, but it may get you started. I suggest `ImageMagick` and `potrace` both of which are free and available for OS X, Linux and Windows. You can integrate them into PHP and run them as library functions, but for now, I am just using the terminal/Commandline.

Let's start by making a chessboard image with ImageMagick

```
convert -size 200x100 pattern:checkerboard chess.jpg
```

[image]

We can now threshold that to make it pure black and white, like this:

```
convert chess.jpg -threshold 50% chessbw.jpg
```

[image]

Then we want to send it to `potrace` to make an `svg`, but that needs a `pbm` format file, so we convert it to `pbm` like this:

```
convert chess.jpg -threshold 50% chessbw.pbm
```

Now we tell `potrace` to convert that into an `svg`

```
potrace -b svg chessbw.pbm -o result.svg
```

but that is not very easy to see, so we get `ImageMagick` to convert `result.svg` into a `JPEG` but with a red background so we can see the transparent areas:

```
convert -background red result.svg result.jpg
```

[image]

Ok, that was more of an explanation than a simple answer, so I will simplify all that down to one command that does the whole lot:

```
convert chess.jpg -threshold 50% pbm:- | potrace -b svg - -o result.svg
```

I hope that helps.